# Obtaining TH.Name for '[] without -XTemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Is there a way to obtain (import from base modules or write expression) a value of type `Language.Haskell.TH.Name` that represents `'[]` without enabling `-XTemplateHaskell`?

A good reason to do so is that tools like hlint do not play well with TH and being able to avoid it therefore has a benefit. Then I could put a definition

```
nilName :: Name
nilName = '[]
```

in a separate file and import it, but this only makes sense if there is no standard name by which it can be imported or called. Furthermore, `nilName` cannot be used in pattern matches. Is there such a thing?

Comment: What's wrong with `mkName "[]"`?

Comment: Try `mkName "[]" == '[]`. It gives `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

nilName = mkNameG DataName "ghc-prim" "GHC.Types" "[]"
```

is an equivalent definition of `nilName`, even though it is ugly. It can be expanded to a form that admits to pattern matching yielding to

```
nilName = Name (OccName "[]") (NameG DataName (PkgName "ghc-prim") (ModName "GHC.Types"))
```

which is not nicer nor robust. It seems that the best route forward is a combination of the above `nilName` defined in a separate TH-enabled module together with `(== nilName)` instead of pattern matching.